# Generic type from string value

Tags: c#, string, parsing, generics, types

I got a custom class, who relies on a generic type T to be passed along.
I only know what type it is in string form, because that's how it's being sent. I've been searching around but can't seem to find exactly what I need.
I can parse the string value to a type, but I need to parse it to... something, that I can pass as a generic parameter.

---

I've rewritten my problem, as such:

```
// Classes structure
namespace Mynamespace
{
    public interface IRequest
    {
    }

    public interface IHandler<T> where T : IRequest
    {
        void Handle(T item);
    }

    public class MyRequest : IRequest
    {
    }

    public class MyHandler : IHandler<MyRequest>
    {
        void Handle(MyRequest item)
        {
        }
    }
}

// The info I get, and I know typeString is a IRequest
string typeString = "My";
object requestItem = [insert xml parsing here];

// I then create a handler, to handle the request
Type typeHandler = Type.GetType("Mynamespace." + typeString + "Handler");
var handler = Activator.CreateInstance(typeHandler);

Type typeRequest = Type.GetType("Mynamespace." + typeString + "Request");

// what I want to do:
handler.Handle(requestItem);
```

I can't do that because handler and requestItem are just objects
So I need to parse 'handler' to 'typeHandler', and requestItem to 'typeRequest'

Edit:
I figured it out, I used InvokeMember to access it. :)

```
typeHandler.InvokeMember("Handle", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, handler, new[] { requestItem });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I used InvokeMember to access it. :)

```
typeHandler.InvokeMember("Handle", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, handler, new[] { requestItem });
```

Answer (score 10):

You need `Type.MakeGenericType`:

```
Type typeArgument = Type.GetType(string.Format("Mynamespace.{0}", typeString));
Type template = typeof(MyClass<>);

Type genericType = template.MakeGenericType(typeArgument);

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Note that you *can't* cast this to a particular `MyClass<T>` because you don't know `T` - but it will be an instance of the right class at execution time.

Comment: +1.  Also note that, although you can't cast the result to a particular `MyClass<T>`, you may want to define a non-generic interface (e.g. `IMyClass`) and cast to that.

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed. I thought I'd hold back from that until the OP gave more information :)

Comment: This is what I sort of do as well already, to create a new instance. But that returns an object, and that object, I need to parse to a MyClass<T>. Because the 'MyClass' has a void that requires the T.

Comment: @Daniel: In my real code I use an interface, and an extra class in between, but I tried here to make a sample of what my problem is, without making it too complicated. :)

Comment: @FrieK: What do you mean, "has a void that requires the T"?  You aren't going to be able to use **compile-time** generic dispatch based on a type that is only determined at **run time** -- it's simply not possible.  Perhaps `dynamic` will do what you want, but I don't understand your problem well enough to be sure.

Comment: Hmm, I think it's the impossible one that I want, but I am rewriting my question to make it more obvious, I hope.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've rewritten my problem, maybe it will make more sense like that. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

```
Type closedType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(myGeneric);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);
```

Note that unless you have a non-generic interface or base-type, it is very tricky to talk to this type of object (unless you cheat by using `dynamic`).  For example, a non-generic interface can be helpful:

```
var obj = (ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);
obj.SomeMethodOnTheNonGenericInterface();
```