# How to convert a string to Class (Generics)

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic type from string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450958/generic-type-from-string-value)

Given a scenario, 
`Class Car: Transport`, 
`Class Bus: Transport`, 
`Interface Transport`,
`Get(): Generics Method`

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Transport t= Get<"Car">(string color);

public T Get<T>(string color)
{
  return new T(color);
}
```

P/S: There's a reason to assign it as string, dynamically, regardless of return type.

Comment: Not the way you are suggesting.  In your case "Car", "Bus", "Bike" will always be a type of string.  You could switch on the string, create and return the appropriate object.

Comment: you dont wanna do that, review your design.

Comment: seen, not answering my question :)

Comment: `(Transport)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("...."))`

Comment: @Roylee I know this doesn't answer your question, so I just moved it to be a comment, but I just wanted to point out that in order for that code to even compile, you would need a `where T : new()` constraint on the generic type parameter `T` in the `Get<T>(string)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want having `Get` works with a string you have two options:
Add a non generic `Get` taking a Type as a paremter, something like:

`public object Get(Type t)`;

so you can pass a type created form a string.
A second option could be reflection:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(YourType).GetMethod("Get");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
```

then you can invoke generic as if it was closed on to the type myType.

If I can suggest which one to use, and if you can refactor the `Get` method, I would suggest adding a non generic version of that method. The reflection version works if you really can't modify the library code. The drawback in using reflection is performance as you probably guess: you can decide if you can stay with it or not.

**EDIT**

Of course, my discussion **does not apply** if your method is really **just creating the final object**:

In this case activator works as a charm by passing the complete type name:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("yourtypename"));
```

You generally can create the type based on just the simple name ( Car,Bus, etc ) because you need to fully qualify with a namespace and an assebly if the type is not the ExecutingAssembly. In this case you have to use some convention/configuration to simplify the code readability.

**ADDITION**

If you need to pass parameters too, I think you can try to start using a simple **IoC** ( I would not recomend one in particular, choose one widely used you like ) that can solve all these issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the class' name at compile type, you won't be able to use generics. You could use `Activator.CreateInstance` though:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedTypeName));
```

This assumes that the type you're creating has a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to get a reference to the type from the type name, then use `Activator.CreateInstance` to, well, create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with generics because a generic argument needs to be resolved at compile time.

However you could certainly pass your type as a string in a parameter and have your method return 'dynamic'.

```
var aCar = Get("Car") as Car;

public dynamic Get(string type)
{
  return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type));
}
```